# Xamarin Forms - How To Display Products in 2 Grid Layout

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have a product page that lists products in ListView format correctly and it's working fine.

[image]

However I want to change this so that it lists products in 2 grid so that you can see more products on the screen.

[image]

I've tried different solutions online but it always tends to break my layout.

How do I do this?

Here's my code:

ProductPage XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="xxx.ProductPage"
             Title="Deals"
             BackgroundColor="Black">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="xxxx.png" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="50"/>
                <ListView x:Name="productsListView"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"                       
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None"
                      ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="20" Margin="20">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding featured_src}"/>
                                        <Label x:Name="labelProductTitle" Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="00">
                                            <Label WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding price , StringFormat='${0:F2}'}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ProductPage CS

```
public List<Product> FinalProducts { get; set; }

        public ProductPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task task = InitAsync();

            productsListView.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                var foo = e.SelectedItem as Product;
                if (foo == null)
                    return;
                Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductDetailPage(foo));
            };

        }

        private async Task InitAsync()
        {
            var api = new WoocommerceAPI();
            var AllProducts = await api.GetAllProducts();
            FinalProducts = AllProducts.products.ToList();
            productsListView.ItemsSource = FinalProducts;
        }
```

Comment: CollectionView will do this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-grid

Comment: @Khoa Hi, if have solved, remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to replace you List With Collection view as Jason mentioned.
you should end up with something like this:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="productsListView">
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
                <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="20" Margin="20">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="{Binding featured_src}"/>
                        <Label x:Name="labelProductTitle" Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="Medium" />
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="00">
                            <Label WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding price , StringFormat='${0:F2}'}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks @Demon is there an alternative to the current "productListView.ItemSelected" to handle clicking on the items for the collection view?

Comment: SelectionChanged

Comment: not sure what alternative you are looking for [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection) should describe everything you need to know about selecting in the collection view. @Jason mentioned also the simple solution (also mentioned in the link).